# How can I replace a local TFS service account with a domain TFS service account to perform a migration?

Tags: team-foundation-server, service-accounts

I changed the service account used by Team Foundation Server from a local account `HOSTNAME\local_tfs_service_account` to a domain account `DOMAIN\domain_tfs_service_account`, by directly clicking on the "`Change Account`" link in the `Application Tier Summary` section.

To verify this, when I click on the `Application Tier` node, I can see that the domain account `DOMAIN\domain_tfs_service_account` is the new service account.

However, when I try to attach a collection that is hosted on another Team Foundation Server (I'm trying to perform a migration), I get the following error:

> [2015-06-16 11:29:45Z][Error] TF255448: The creation of a SQL Server
>   login failed for the following account:
>   `HOSTNAME\local_tfs_service_account`. You must manually create a SQL Server
>   login and then retry this operation. You must create the login on the
>   following SQL Server instance: `source_server`.

Of course, the operation fails, since the server that is hosting the source TFS collection cannot know about the local service account.

But why is Team Foundation still using the old service account `HOSTNAME\local_tfs_service_account`? I've only left the local account `HOSTNAME\local_tfs_service_account` as the reader account for Reporting Services.

What do I need to do to complete the change? Should I restart the server, etc? Or is there some other location that I also need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change from a local to a domain account this is a big deal for TFS. It's effectively a domain migration from local to domain.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883.aspx

You need to follow the documented procedure for changing the environment within which TFS operates.